# TFS: Shelveset name in Build Template .xaml file

Tags: tfs

How to get shelveset name of the gated-check-in which is triggered in Build Template .xaml file?

I want pass shelveset name to a process which is called using InvokeProcess tool in .xaml file.

I am new to TFS, any inputs will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this property? I did not test it, but check it out: BuildDetail.ShelvesetName

[BuildDetail.ShelvesetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.server.builddetail.shelvesetname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom activity reusing [some code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7ebea82-bbc4-4ed2-b138-30ce5e9f0ec7/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-changesets-or-work-items-associated-with-these-css-that-were-checkedin?forum=tfsbuild).